# Can I reuse a signal that is assigned values within a different process?

Tags: vhdl, hardware

I have created a process that assigns values to a signal in the purpose of re-using the signal within a different process:

```
Signaling : process(button0, button1)
begin

  if (button1= '0') AND (button0 = '0') then  -- if both buttons are pressed
    BothButtons <= "00";
  elsif (button1 = '0') AND (button0 = '1') then  -- if button1 is pressed
    BothButtons <= "01";
  elsif (button1 = '1') AND (button0 = '0') then  -- if button0 is pressed
    BothButtons <= "10";
  elsif (button1 = '1') AND (button0 = '1') then -- if no button are pressed
    BothButtons <= "11";
  else
    --BothButtons <= "11";
    BothButtons <= button0 & button1;
  end if;

end process;
```

The other process which I am re-using this signal is:

```
Counting : process(button0, BothButtons) 

  variable count0 : integer range 0 to 9; -- to hold the counter value

begin 

  if falling_edge(Button0) then -- I am using button0 as a clock because the onboard clock is too fast  

    if BothButtons = "00" then
      count0 := 0;
    elsif BothButtons = "01" then
      count0 := count0 + 1;
    elsif BothButtons = "10" then
      count0 := count0 + 1;
    else
      count0 := count0 + 1; -- when i have included this i have discovered that the signal value is not visible within this process
  end if;

end process;
```

Please ignore the contents of this if-statement I know it does not make sense but  am just testing to see if the signals value is visisble within this process!

The output is not as expected, it does not seem like the second process is responding to changes within the signal!

Comment: Maybe I should create a function that assigns the signal values within the same process!

Comment: Yes, you can assign a signal in one process, and read it in another. Is there something more to your question?

Comment: @scary_jeff oh thanks, any suggestions to why it is not working?

Comment: Define "not working", we aren't psychic. First, did it do what you expected in simulation? Then - if so, what does it do differently in hardware?

Comment: @BrianDrummond the output is not as expected, it does not seem like that the second process is responding to changes within the signal, I used button0 to simulate a clock as the on-board FPGA clock is too fast, i have replaced the first process with a single concurrent statement as suggested below but there is still something else which I am failing to spot! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: yes. As a rule of thumb, write to your signal in only one process (this is the signal 'driver'), and read it in any other process.

It's a bit more complicated than this, but you can ignore the complications to start with. You actually write to the signal in an 'effective process' (which can be a concurrent assignment, for example, instead of a process), and you can have multiple drivers if you want to deal with resolution functions.

Your code is all messed up, though. First, you have major race problems. both processes are sensitive to the same signals and you don't know what order they'll execute in. Second, your first process can be completely replaced with a simple concurrent assignment (the one in your else branch). Your second process is also too complicated.

Comment: thanks that makes sense, now I relies how stupid I am! I'll give it a shot!

Comment: I have taken your advice and made changes accordingly, what would you advise on what is messed up with the second process?

Comment: I have managed to solve it, I was triggering events on a falling edge while it should have been the opposite! 1 to 0 was my rising edge and 0 to 1 was a falling edge, this is how the button work on my FPGA but technically aren't both triggered when the button is pressed and unpressed! because 0 to 1 is pressed and 1 to 0 is when a finger is removed of the button!

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed to write to a signal in one process and read it in one or more other processes. You are however never allowed to write to the same signal from more than one process, which isn't the case here.